# linear distribution in c++ using rand()

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, distribution

I am writing a function that generates n random numbers x such that xmin < x < xmax. This is easy to do with uniform distribution using rand().

```
int points[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    points[i] = rand() % (xmax - xmin) + xmin;
}
```

However, I would like to control the distribution so that the probability of a given x value is `px = (px2 * (x - xmin) + px1 * (xmax - x)) / (xmax - xmin)`, where px1 and px2 are constants. In other words, a linear distribution.

I can fake this by partitioning the interval into sufficiently small discrete intervals and using the algorithm above for each one, with n proportional to the average probability across the subinterval. However, I would prefer to apply a continuous distribution across the interval. Can this be done, either using rand() or with another approach?

Comment: Can you use C++11 or above? There's a nice `<random>` header that provides much better random number facilities than `rand`.

Comment: x and y are still independent, though, no? Nothing in your statement makes x dependent on y or v.v.  So if you can find a function which provides the distribution you want, you should be able to randomly select a point by randomly selecting x and randomly selecting y. (Also, what are p{x,y}{1,2}? Constants? Distributions?)

Comment: @rici True. I guess the problem can be simplified to one dimension. And yes, those values are constants.

Comment: Please, watch [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and stop using `rand`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PDF proportional to some linear function, CDF will be proportional to `x` squared . Thus, sampling would require sqrt(), something along the lines

```
x = xmin + sqrt(urand())*(xmax - xmin);
y = ymin + sqrt(urand())*(ymax - ymin);
```

where urand() is U(0,1) RNG (probably equal to `rand()/RAND_MAX`, but I've abandoned rand() and moved to C++11 long time ago)

UPDATE

If you want to use your `p1` and `p2` (assuming they are probabilities such that p1+p2=1), there would be a bit of modification, first to select which branch to sample:

```
r1 = urand();
if (r1 < p2) // range [0...p2), first branch
    x = xmin + sqrt(urand())*(xmax-xmin);
else // range [p2...1), range length is 1-p2=p1
    x = xmax - sqrt(urand())*(xmax-xmin);
```

Similar sampling for `y`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try something along those lines and look in to C++11 and <random>